# How to use normal button instead of bar button item

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton

Guys I am using the swRevealViewController for my slide menu and I requires a bar button item to trigger the sliding of the menu. I have the navigation bar hidden.How can I do this with a normal button since it does not have a "target" and "action"

```
Open.target = self.revealViewController()
Open.action = Selector("revealToggle:")
```

Open is the bar button item.

Answer (score 1):

You can create Your Own button and display it. simple.

The following code simulates the behaviour of the back button including animation.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
        UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"UINavigationBarBackIndicatorDefault"]];
        [imageView setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc] init];
        [label setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [label setText:@"Blog"];
        [label sizeToFit];

        int space=6;
        label.frame=CGRectMake(imageView.frame.origin.x+imageView.frame.size.width+space, label.frame.origin.y, label.frame.size.width, label.frame.size.height);
        UIView *view=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, label.frame.size.width+imageView.frame.size.width+space, imageView.frame.size.height)];

        view.bounds=CGRectMake(view.bounds.origin.x+8, view.bounds.origin.y-1, view.bounds.size.width, view.bounds.size.height);
        [view addSubview:imageView];
        [view addSubview:label];

        //instead of adding the button, in my opinion the better approach is to use a gesture recognizer.

        UITapGestureRecognizer* tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleBack:)];
        [view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
        [view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.33 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
            label.alpha = 0.0;
            CGRect orig=label.frame;
            label.frame=CGRectMake(label.frame.origin.x+25, label.frame.origin.y, label.frame.size.width, label.frame.size.height);
            label.alpha = 1.0;
            label.frame=orig;
        } completion:nil];

        UIBarButtonItem *backButton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:view];
}

- (void) handleBack:(id)sender{
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, I only know Swift

Comment: ohk. sorry Daniel you have to search. i don't know swift.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort

Comment: thank you. Daniel..  keep coding.. whenever you need help tell me, i will be there for you. my friend

Answer (score 0):

You can use the addTarget method of the UIButton like this:

```
yourButton.addTarget(self.revealViewController(), action: "revealToggle:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding Custom barbutton item in SWRevealViewController

```
    let revealController = SWRevealViewController()
    let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "menu-icon.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal);
    button.addTarget(revealController, action: "revealToggle:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton
```

Answer (score 0):

This is code by Mehul translated into Swift. I have not tested it, just translated:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "UINavigationBarBackIndicatorDefault"))
    imageView.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
    let label = UILabel.init()
    label.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
    label.text = "Blog"
    label.sizeToFit()

    let space = 6 as CGFloat
    label.frame = CGRectMake(imageView.frame.origin.x+imageView.frame.size.width+space, label.frame.origin.y, label.frame.size.width, label.frame.size.height)
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, label.frame.size.width+imageView.frame.size.width+space, imageView.frame.size.height))

    view.bounds = CGRectMake(view.bounds.origin.x+8, view.bounds.origin.y-1, view.bounds.size.width, view.bounds.size.height)
    view.addSubview(imageView)
    view.addSubview(label)

    //instead of adding the button, in my opinion the better approach is to use a gesture recognizer.

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleBack:")
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    view.userInteractionEnabled = true

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.33, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: {

        label.alpha = 0
        let orig = label.frame
        label.frame = CGRectMake(label.frame.origin.x+25, label.frame.origin.y, label.frame.size.width, label.frame.size.height)
        label.alpha = 1
        label.frame = orig

        }, completion: nil)

    let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: view)

}

func handleBack(sender: AnyObject) {
}
```